# crazy number of divisors chart on Wikipedia - $\Omega(n)$

Tags: number-theory, statistics

I am learning about [factorization into primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#.CE.A9.28n.29.2C_.CF.89.28n.29.2C_.CE.BDp.28n.29_.E2.80.93_prime_power_decomposition) and I learned about the <del>sum</del> number of divisors function (counting multiplicity).

$$ \Omega(n) = \Omega \left(\prod p_i^{a_i}\right) = \sum a_i $$

The same wikipedia article has this wonderful chart using data from Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

[image]

However this is **not** the plot of the sum of divisors function which looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Neither of these look like the Brownian motion chart above.  Is there an asymptotic result here?  Here is caption from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#mediaviewer/File:PrimeFactorAmounts.svg):

> The chaotic course of Ω(n) through the natural numbers (OEIS A001222): Beginning on the height of the red line the two least significant binary digits of Ω(n) of all positive odd n below 1200 are represented by a line up (digit 1) or a line down (digit 0). **The additional replacement of the “↗↘” of the semiprimes without prime factors below 5 by only one line down (here blue) even almost brings a balance between the ups and downs.** The prime numbers are marked orange: orange lines for the Gaussian primes and for the other primes p additional the number x in orange so that p = x² + y² = (x + yi) (x – yi) = –i (x + yi) (y + xi) and x < y for natural x and y (OEIS A002331).

Using only the last two bits of $\Omega(n)$ and doing the addition, I actually get an upward drift:

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

- if we restrict to $n$ odd, the last two binary digits of $\Omega(n)$ exhibit chaotic behavior
- being divisible by 5 seems to lead to an up-down ↗↘ pattern
- Gaussian primes may have special meaning, but are not important to draw the chart

Can anyone help me understand this balance?

---

**UPDATE** The [Erdos-Kac Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem) says that without multiplicity, $ \omega(n) \sim \mathcal{N}(\log \log n, \log \log n) $ should be a standard normal.  Here is an article by [Granville + Soundarajan](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/ErdosKac.pdf) and the original article by [Erdoc+Kac](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183507847).  I am not sure if this is what the above chart from Wikipedia is showing.

Comment: $\Omega(n)$ is not the "sum of divisors". It's the number of prime factors (counting multiplicity, unlike $\omega(n)$).